# Check using jquery height if one element of any has height zero

Tags: jquery, height

I've got this

```
    if ($("#sidebar .box_cuerpo").height() == "0") {
           //blaaa
    }
```

But sometimes on other pages inside site there are more than one "#sidebar .box_cuerpo " elements... and also some are not height 0.

is it possible to check on all elements and if almost one is height 0 that statement it's true?

Comment: How do you mean "almost one"? Do you mean if any of the elements have height 0?

Comment: Is there more than one #sidebar on a page?

Comment: j08691: No, only one #sidebar
Christofer Eliasson: Yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to reduce the collection.
`.filter` executes the given function for each element in the collection. If the function returns `true`, the element is kept. Otherwise (`false`), the element is discarded.

```
if ($("#sidebar .box_cuerpo").filter(function() {
    return $(this).height() === 0;
}).length) {
    //blaaa
}
```